# Can I truncate file size stored on Google Drive using their GDrive Api (JAVA)?

Tags: java, file, google-drive-api, truncate

Is it possible to truncate file to desired length using Google drive API? Or I can only replace file content by uploading fresh new data (shorter)? If this is not possible, that is really sad, because this would be very useful function.

I'm asking because I want to edit some file footers and in case I'm editing larger file, replacing it's contents takes time and resources. It would be fantastic, if it could be done without moving lots of data from outside gdrive.

Thank you, Josef

Comment: The answer using the Drive API is 'no'. What is the mime type of the file you want to truncate?

Comment: I was hoping the opposite. But doc indicated/said what you just said. Thank you. 

But generally. I want Google manipulate big files, instead of transferring huge amount of data to client, editing them and putting them back. Mime type is raw/binary = application/vnd.google-apps.file, application/octet-stream. 

Idea is to store some user specific data to the end of file and change only those... because basic file stream doesn't need to be changed. Footer only.

Imagine time& resource savings if you just truncate file and send new footer... In case where file body is 4GB long and footer is 1kB.

Comment: And yes, I was already thinking about "growing" footer, when each new footer invalidates previous ones... But this is not clean. You know what I mean.

Comment: you might need to front-end Drive with an app to achieve what you're looking for. So you store files as fragments in Drive and your app manages the splitting and concatenation as required. That's all I can suggest.

Comment: Yep, that will definitely work. But ... two files for one. I will need to discuss it with my colleagues.